# How to create smooth vertical carousel web?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, carousel

I want to create a smooth vertical carousel for my product list, I want to build it for my Kiosk Machine which use touchscreen media and have the smooth vertical carousel and scroll-able.

A bit of confused what library/tools with I should use.

Here what I can do: https://codepen.io/DilrajPutra10/pen/bPvQmM

```
$('.slick-carousel').slick({
  vertical:true,
  verticalSwiping:true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 0,
  speed:9000,
  cssEase: 'linear',
  infinite: true,
  arrows:false,
});
```

On codepen, I can create the smooth scrolling effect but I cannot scroll it

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a `click_handler` function such that the carousel will only start when the user clicks the `slick-carousel`.

```
function click_handler() {


     $('.slick-carousel').slick({
            vertical:true,
            verticalSwiping:true,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 0,
            speed: 9000,
            cssEase: 'linear',
            infinite: false,
            arrows:false,
      });
}
```

Note parameter `infinite` is set to false here.

In the html, you add this

```
<div class="slick-carousel" onclick="click_handler(this)">
```

Comment: But it still can not be scrolled? The autoplay works fine, and the vertical carousel is smooth, but how to make it scrollable ??